# gatsby-source-medium thumbnail image not showing

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I'm using gatsby in my react project, to show my medium, articles inside the project.

below is my graphql query for that.

```
const BlogPost = () => {
  const blogMediumQueryData = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query Medium {
      allMediumPost(sort: { fields: [createdAt], order: DESC }) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            title
            uniqueSlug
            createdAt(formatString: "MMM YYYY")
            virtuals {
              previewImage {
                imageId
              }
            }
            author {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const blogs = blogMediumQueryData.allMediumPost.edges
return (
    <Blog
        image={blog.node.virtuals.previewImage.imageId}
        title={blog.node.title}
        date={blog.node.createdAt}
        author={blog.node.author.name}
        path={blog.node.uniqueSlug}
     />
  )
```

this gives me the preview image ID. And I'm passing it to the child component as a prop. But when I try to show the image with the Img component from gatsby, the Image is not showing.

Here is my code for the child component

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import { slugify } from "../utils/utilityFunctions"
import Image from "../elements/image"

const Blog = ({ image }) => {
  return (
    <div className="content-block">
      <div className="post-thubnail">
        {image && (
          <Link to={postUrl} target='blank'>
            <Image src={image} alt={title} />
          </Link>
        )}
      </div>
  )
}
export default Blog
```

Here is the code for the Image component

```
import React from "react";
import Img from "gatsby-image";

const NonStretchedImage = props => {
    let normalizedProps = props
    normalizedProps = {...normalizedProps.fluid, aspectRatio: 1}
    let alignment;
    if(props.align === 'right'){
        alignment = '0 0 0 auto'
    } else if(props.align === 'left'){
        alignment = '0 auto 0 0'
    }else{
        alignment = '0 auto'
    }

    if (props.fluid && props.fluid.presentationWidth) {
        normalizedProps = {
            ...props,
            style: {
                ...(props.style || {}),
                maxWidth: props.fluid.presentationWidth,
                margin: alignment, 
            },
        }
    }

    return <Img {...normalizedProps} />
}

export default NonStretchedImage;
```

This is my first project with gatsby and graphql. Is there are anything that I have missed or is there anything that I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few caveats that I guess will put you on the track to fix the issue.

`node`, in the GraphQL query is an array, in the same way, I guess that `virtuals` it is. Check and test the response in the `localhost:8000/___graphql` playground.

So assuming that your query works as expected, your code should look like:

```
const BlogPost = () => {
  const blogMediumQueryData = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query Medium {
      allMediumPost(sort: { fields: [createdAt], order: DESC }) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            title
            uniqueSlug
            createdAt(formatString: "MMM YYYY")
            virtuals {
              previewImage {
                imageId
              }
            }
            author {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const blogs = blogMediumQueryData.allMediumPost.edges
return (
    <Blog
        image={blog.node[0].virtuals.previewImage.imageId}
        title={blog.node[0].title}
        date={blog.node[0].createdAt}
        author={blog.node[0].author.name}
        path={blog.node[0].uniqueSlug}
     />
  )
```

Alternatively, you can loop through the array of nodes and use your previous `Blog` component since it will get each iterable variable.

I don't think your `Image` component be able to render a `gatsby-image` only using the `imageId`. Gatsby needs a bunch of data (given by its transformers and sharps) to render the image, not using an identifier but series of fields (that's why it usually renders query fragments, noted by `...`). Your image component, in the end, should render something like:

```
<img src={`https://medium.com/${blog.node[0].virtuals.previewImage.imageId}`}
```

*Based on: https://blog.devgenius.io/how-to-scrap-your-medium-articles-with-gatsby-js-f35535ebc09d*

So summarizing, `gatsby-source-medium` by itself doesn't provide enough data to use `gatsby-image` or `gatsby-image-plugin` plugins so I'm afraid you won't be able to use the `Img` component. You have to use the standard `img` tag.